# Intuitive Difference between "square matrix with no inverse" vs non-square matrix ???

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

When we deal with square matrix $A$ of size $3\times 3$ and $\det(A)=0$, means our output after transformation lies in lesser dimensional space. Instead if deal with a non-square matrix $B$ of size $2\times 3$ means a 3D vector is transformed to 2D vector. What is the intuitive difference in the two formulations?

Comment: Using your words: What is the intuitive analogy in the two formulations? I don't see any, the first matrix has $9$ entries, while the second has $6$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first case, *the mapping is necessarily* **not onto**.

In  second case, *it is not necessary that the mapping is* **onto**.

Comment: yeah..thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, the union of all outputs is a plane (or a line or a point) in $\mathbb{R}^3$. In the second case, the union of all outputs is $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or a line or a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$). Intuitively, we have a three dimensional space with a plane in it in the first scenario, while we have nothing but a plane in the second scenario.

Comment: ok.thanks....But can u tell me any specific application where using these different formulations make sense...i mean wen d output of both is same...y two approaches..?

Comment: First of all, the output is not the same. Even if the output can be interpreted as a plane in both cases, there is a fundamental difference: The plane in the first case can have different positions in the 3-dimensional space.

Comment: Secondly, you usually do not choose the matrix, it is determined by the problem (e.g. optimize the usage of 3 resource for the production of 3 different products). And in practice, if there is a $n\times n$-matrix, and you do not know if it could be singular, you won't try do transform it into a matrix with lesser dimensions. You will choose a robust numerical method that can deal with badly conditioned matrices, instead.

Comment: means its application dependent..thanks...:)